# Reactjs Cannot update the value of provision category_price

Tags: reactjs

Reactjs Cannot update the value of provision category_price.

The **Reactjs** code below displays provisions records from the arrays.

Now I need to update and replace the value the category_price from **100 USD** to **500 USD.**

To this effect, I  have added an update button which fetch the category_price from the Axios Call when clicked.

My problem is that **CATEGORY_PRICE** is not updated with 500 usd when the button is clicked.

In the console, I can see the **500 usd** via this code when button is clicked: `console.log(response.data[0].category_price)`

**Here is the json response of Axios Call for category_price updates**

price.json

```
[{"category_price":"500 USD"}]
```

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      data: [{
        "provision_id":"1",
        "provision":"Milk",
        "category":[{"category_id":"1", "category_price":"100 USD" }]
      }],
    });
  }

  // Get and update New Price of Milk
  handleNewPrice(pro_id) {
    alert(pro_id);
    const product = {
      pro_id: pro_id};
      axios
        .get("http://localhost/provision/price.json", { product })
        .then(response => {
          const newData = this.state.data.map(store => {
            if (store.provision_id !== pro_id) return store;
              return { ...store, category_price: response.data[0].category_price };
            });
            this.setState(state => ({
              data: newData
            }));
            console.log(response.data[0].category_price);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <span>
          <label>
            <ul>
              {this.state.data.map((store) => {
                return (
                  <div key={store.provision_id}>
                    <div><h1>Provision Store</h1> <br />
                      <b> Product: </b>{store.provision} 
                    </div>
                    {store.category && store.category.map((cat) => {
                      return (
                        <div key={cat.category_id}>
                          <div><b>Prices:</b> {cat.category_price}
                            <br />
                            <input
                              type="button"
                              value="Get & Update New Price"
                              onClick={() => this.handleNewPrice(cat.category_id)}
                            />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )
                    })}
                  </div>
                )
              }
            )}
          </ul>
        </label>
      </span>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @BlunderingPhilosopher for reindenting the code, I edited my answer removing my reindentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property category of your 'store' object is an array, so here:

```
return { ...store, category_price: response.data[0].category_price };
```

you are adding a `category_price` property at the root of them.
You should write something like:

```
return {
  ...store, 
  category: [{
    ...store.category,
    category_price: response.data[0].category_price
  }]
};
```

This syntax will work only if you have an array `category` with a single element in it, otherwise you should map it too in relation with the category_id that the method receive as a parameter:

```
return {
  ...store, 
  category: store.category.map(
    category => {
      if (category.category_id !== pro_id) return category
      return { ...category, category_price: response.data[0].category_price }
    }
  )
}
```

I would say, just as a suggestion, to better evaluate your variables name, because I find them very error prone.

For instance, in your onClick handler you call a method passing a property called `category_id` on the `cat` object.

```
<input
  type="button"
  value="Get & Update New Price"
  onClick={() => this.handleNewPrice(cat.category_id)}
/>
```

Then, in the signature of that method, you call it `pro_id`, which seems more "product-related" and, in fact, you later use it in "product-like" manner:

```
handleNewPrice(pro_id) {
  alert(pro_id);
  const product = { pro_id: pro_id };
```

Now, I don't know your codebase, so I really can't tell you if it is correct or not, but surely is error prone, you can agree with me.

It's very, veeery important to name things properly and clearly.
Consider, also, that you almost never need to abbreviate things making them less understandable, characters are free :)

Comment: Thanks alot 0xc14m1z, Your solution works excellent for me. I can now get the new updated  price.  now  I have also added product number on the array on my new question post on my profile and am  using your solution to get it but its showing map error.  btw thanks alot

Comment: Glad to help Nancy. I just answered to your other question.